# How do I make a concatenation? VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a `ListView` that is filled with `TextBoxes` data, I need that when saving all the values ​​are saved concatenated in this way:

[image]

Value / Value

But it keeps me like this:

Value / / Value

[[image: IMAGE[1]]

How can you fix it?

This is my code to button save:

```vb
        Dim StringPrefijoTel As String
        Dim StringNumeroTel As String


        Dim StringPrefijoCel As String
        Dim StringNumeroCel As String

        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To List_Contactos.ListItems.Count
            If List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(1) = "Fijo" Then
                StringPrefijoTel = List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(2)
                If StringNumeroTel = "" Then
                    StringNumeroTel = List_Contactos.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(3) + " / " + StringNumeroTel
                Else
                    StringNumeroTel = StringNumeroTel + " / " + List_Contactos.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(3)
                End If


                Rs!actelcli = StringNumeroTel
                Rs!preFijo = StringPrefijoTel
            Else
                StringPrefijoCel = List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(2)
                If StringNumeroCel = "" Then
                    StringNumeroCel = List_Contactos.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(3) + " / " + StringNumeroCel
                Else
                    StringNumeroCel = StringNumeroCel + " / " + List_Contactos.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(3)
                End If


                Rs!preCelu = StringPrefijoCel
                Rs!Celu = StringNumeroCel
            End If
        Next i
```

Comment: Place breakpoints on the lines that perform the concatenation.  Inspect the contents of the variables being concatenated.  One of variables will have a trailing or leading `/`.

Comment: The debugger is your friend. It should quickly show that the first time through the loop, your string will end with /. The second time through the loop, you start by appending a /.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to not have the string end with `/`.  There are several ways to accomplish this goal but here's how I would structure the code:

```vb
For i = 1 To List_Contactos.ListItems.Count
   If List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(1) = "Fijo" Then
      StringPrefijoTel = List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(2)
      StringNumeroTel = StringNumeroTel & List_Contactos.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(3) & " / "
   Else
      StringPrefijoCel = List_Contactos.ListItems(i).SubItems(2)
      StringNumeroCel = StringNumeroCel & List_Contactos.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(3) & " / "
   End If
Next i

Rs!actelcli = Left(StringNumeroTel, Len(StringNumeroTel) - 3)
Rs!preFijo = StringPrefijoTel
Rs!Celu = Left(StringNumeroCel, Len(StringNumeroCel) - 3)
Rs!preCelu = StringPrefijoCel
```

A few comments.  First, keep your loop simple and don't worry about the extra `/`.  You can take care of that later.  Second, the RecordSet stuff doesn't need to be inside the loop.  It doesn't hurt anything, but I would move it outside the loop.  Third, don't forget to remove the extra trailing `/` before you save the data.

Also, concatenation uses the `&` not the `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Replace function in VB6 to replace all double slashes with a single slash like this : `a = Replace(StringToFind,"//","/")`